# Attribute Assistant choose GenerateID Sequence Name based on Location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-assistant

I am trying to set up Attribute Assistant to populate the UNITID field in my Manhole feature class. The problem i am facing is that the county is split up into four regions; NW, NE, SE, SW. and the UNITID field is set up to have the region first and then that regions unique number.  Example NE003 or SW046.  Each of these regions has their own Sequence Counters and are independent from each other.  So is there a way to say: IF manhole is placed in NW Region then use the NW Sequence Name in the GenerateID table? It is not as simple as the Generate ID By Intersect Method because the name of the sequence is based on the Manholes location.  Hope all that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the **Generate ID By Intesect** method is the one you need.

To test I created a grid with NW, NE, SE, SW, and put those region names into the attribute table in the field `GRIDID` (although this fieldname can be different)

[image]

The `GenerateID` table is populated with the sequence name and each region ID (NW, NE, SE, SW), and the sequence counter and interval set (I started with `1` in the counter, but it has increased as I added new points)

[image]

In the `DynamicValue` table you need to set the `Table Name` to your Manholes layer, `Field Name` to the ID field in the Manholes, `Value Method` to `GENERATE_ID_BY_INTERSECT` and in `Value Info` you need to put the following:

```
CityGrid|GRIDID|GRIDSEQ|3|[ID][SEQ]
```

where:

- `CityGrid` is the name of your region grid
- `GRIDID` is the name of the field in your region grid that holds the region ID (NW, NE, SE, SW)
- `GRIDSEQ` is the name of the sequence in GenerateID table that when coupled with the region name (`NW` etc.) will identify which sequence to use
- `3` is padding on the sequence value
- `[ID][SEQ]` puts the region ID (`NW` etc.) with the sequence to produce something like `NW003` as the manhole ID.

[image]

This outputs a new ID for each feature based on the region you create the feature in

[image]

Comment: Thank You!  I must have read the rules for the Generate ID By Intersect method incorrectly.  Cheers

Comment: @kbrenn89 I have found that with the Attribute Assistant sometimes it actually requires a sit down and test to see how it works, rather than just rely on the description.